# Transparent Background image on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, background

I've succeeded to upload an image as a background of a JPanel, but I don't know how to make the JPanel children fit on it. For example, when I add a button or CHeckbox, their surface appears.
How can I add a button to a jpanel (with image as background) without having that rectangle.
here is my code :

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel{

    BufferedImage backgroundImage;

    public BackgroundPanel() throws Exception
      {
        // load background image
        backgroundImage=javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("/home/imanopholist/Bureau/bg17.jpg"));
        // set the panel size to the dimension of the background image
        int panelWidth=backgroundImage.getWidth(null);
        int panelHeight=backgroundImage.getHeight(null);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(panelWidth,panelHeight));

      }
     public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics gr)
      {
        gr.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,null);

      }
     }
         // My panel :
          try {
            bgpanel=new BackgroundPanel();

            bgpanel.setLayout(null);
            bgpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(785, 595));
            pan1.add(bgpanel);
            bgpanel.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // My Label
        JLabel lblNbrServices = new JLabel("Number of Services");
        lblNbrServices.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNbrServices.setBounds(500, 110, 145, 29);
        bgpanel.add(lblNbrServices);
```

[The Interface]

Comment: post your code so far, and also an expected result to clarify... ;)

Comment: Ok, it's done .........................................

Comment: "*their surface appears*" What do you mean? Screenshot?

Comment: I tried but it tells me that I need 10 reputation to post an image. what I mean is when I add a checkbox on a black background, I can see the white surface of the checkbox on the black background.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a `BasicPanelUI` . Create one like this ,

```
BasicPanelUI UI = new BasicPanelUI() {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,null);                
    }
};
```

And attach to your `JPanel` like this

```
this.setUI(UI);
```

Other components can be added without any problem

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it didn't work. here's what've done : public class setBackgroundImage {

 static JPanel pane=new JPanel();
 static BufferedImage backg;
 static BasicPanelUI UI = new BasicPanelUI() {
  
     @Override
     
     public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c)  {
         g.drawImage(backg,0,0,null);                
     }
 };

 
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 
  backg=ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("/home/imanopholist/Bureau/bg.jpg"));

  pane.setUI(UI);
  
  pane.add(new JCheckBox("Salut ************* "));

Comment: Had you load the image before setting the UI ? It does not look like so

Comment: here's my mail : blacky.white@live.fr , Can you send me yours, I want to show you my code and what I did.